# how to remove script tag such {audio}{/audio} or {youtube}{/youtube}

Tags: php, joomla

in my old data it store joomla tags such "{audio}{/audio}" or "{youtube}{/youtube}", and I want to strip these tag.

how I do in php code? if I want leave it content or remove it content.

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regular expression`

```
$match = "/\{audio\}[^{]*\{\/audio}/";
$replace = "";
$text = "your joomla text which has {audio}something{/audio}";

$output = preg_replace($match, $replace, $text);
```

This method removes any text that is in between {audio}{/audio} tags, if that's not what you want change

```
$match = "/\{audio\}([^{]*)\{\/audio}/";
$replace = "\\$0";
```

which will leave the content in the middle back in the output text.

Comment: but php said: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'a'

Comment: you need to escape {/audio} with {\/audio}

Answer (score 0):

Compared to regular expression replace function `str_replace()` is a lot faster.

```
$text = str_replace("{audio}", "", $text);
$text = str_replace("{\/audio}", "", $text);
```